# Plot as you go in MATLAB

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I'm self studying some numerical analysis and I'd like to get a feel for how an ODE solver speed varies as you move forward in time. Is it possible to use matlab to numerically solve an equation (using ode45 or similar) and plot the solution points as they are obtained?

Comment: "As you move forward in time" with respect to *what*?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just do it within a loop, put some pause after each plot.

Comment: Ugh, that's not how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want to plot solutions in real time or if you want to evaluate the step size of the method.

In the first case, it doesn't make sense to plot solutions to `ode45` in real time; `ode45` uses a Dormand-Prince or a Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg 4(5) pair adaptive solver to compute the solutions, depending on the version of MATLAB that you have. In either case, the step size of the $n+1$ step cannot be computed until the $n$th step is computed, which means that unless your adaptation happens in sub-real time, you can't guarantee a real-time view.

However, the *purpose* of adaptive solvers is to accelerate solutions to be *faster* than real time while attaining accuracy better than fixed-step solvers. So in this sense it doesn't make much sense to look at real-time solutions, either.

However, if you want to evaluate the adapatation of the solver, you simply need to execute the following code:

```
[t,y] = ode45(f,tspan y0);
delta_t = t(2:end)-t(1:end-1);
plot(1:length(t)-1, delta_t);
```

Comment: ... where `tspan` is a two-element vector. Otherwise, as you know, interpolated dense output is returned as opposed to the true steps. Also +1 for an on-topic answer to a likely off-topic question.

Comment: I should also mention that, as a commenter said, restarting `ode45` in a loop will **not** give you what you want. First, you will need to be careful that the initial conditions at the $k+1$ step are the output of the $k$th step. Second, you cannot guarantee the adaptive sizes from `k=1:K` would be the same as from `t=1:T`. In fact, they likely *will not be.*

Comment: The  `’Refine'` option may also need to be set to `1` in the case of `ode45` to get the true steps.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my poorly stated question. To clarify, I'm wondering about how the time (in FLOPS?) required to compute a solution varies with the number of steps (or step size for solvers with fixed step size). ode45 was a poor example since it is a variable step size method so say I'm working with something simpler like Euler. If I double the density of the points in the interval the amount of computational effort increases but I'm not sure what the relationship is. Does each step take the same amount of computing time?

Comment: Don't count flops, count function calls. Euler requires one. RK4 requires 4. That's the relevant quantity. You can count flops inside your function if you want.

Comment: And we assume, more or less correctly for **most** functions that a function call takes the same amount of time regardless of the argument. Stiff functions and piece wise nonlinear functions will break this assumption